# Cloudant: No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields

Tags: database, sorting, nosql, couchdb, cloudant

I have a problem that persists for a few days and I cannot solve it.

I have a simple document in my database which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "asd123",
  "_rev": "revidasd123",
  "type": "CUSTOM_TYPE",
  "position": 8,
  "title": "Short custom title"
}
```

When I try to make a sort by *position*, even if I have created an index for this field, I always get the same error:

> **Error: no_usable_index. Reason: No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields**.

Here is the index:

```
{
 "type": "json",
 "def": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "position": "asc"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

And here is my query which cause this error:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "type": "CUSTOM_TYPE",
    "_id":{
      "$gt": null
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "type",
    "position"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": "asc"
    },
    {
      "position": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result: **No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.**

Please **HELP!** Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort by position then try this query:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "type": "CUSTOM_TYPE",
    "position": {"$gte": 0}
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "type",
    "position"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "position": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `position` field needs to be part of the selector. I set it to match any position that is >= 0, so it should match all unless it's null.

Also, you were sorting by `_id` and then `position`. This would render the `position` sort meaningless. I removed the `_id` field from the sort.

Comment: Thank you very much, @markwatsonatx. 
This solved my problem.
I also included position in the selector but I did not removed _id, so probably that threw me an error too..